# Are Oracle call timeouts atomic?

Tags: oracle, odpi-c

I'm running Oracle 19c with the cx_Oracle Python connector and I'm getting this error.

```
DPI-1067: call timeout of 15000 ms exceeded with ORA-3156
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error when attempting to commit.

Because this is so hard to reproduce in a development environment I have no idea if this is safe.  If a call timeout happens in Oracle when committing, *will the commit be rolled back*?

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively. My expectation is that once Oracle RDBMS begins a commit operation, it would not be interrupted by a loss of communication with the client that issued the command.  I think you should be asking why your commit takes 15 seconds.

Comment: If the commit fails then the transaction should still be open and uncommitted.  If a session disappears with an open transaction, it should be rolled back.  If you're dealing with distributed transactions, you could be left with an in-doubt transaction.  But it isn't obvious if the problem is that the actual `commit` statement is failing or the client is losing contact with the server for some reason in which case the `commit` might be succeeding and the client is timing out waiting for the response.

Comment: Any chance you have an `on commit` materialized view?  That's the only thing I can think of that would potentially cause the actual `commit` operation to take a long time other than a distributed transaction.

Comment: @DaveCosta hey believe me, I'm trying to work out why the commits block :)  It's not my project and I'm trying to fix things.

Comment: @JustinCave I don't have any materialised views.

Comment: Thing is, I don't know if the commits fail or not. From my own logs I looks like sometimes objects are created even when things time out.

Comment: This database does have a lot of triggers.  Like dirty triggers that update other rows on inserts.

Comment: Are you doing distributed transactions?  Are there any in-doubt transactions (rows in `dba_2pc_pending` or `dba_2pc_neighbors`?

Comment: No I doubt it.  We're just running standard edition.